# Insert records from CSV file into Oracle, with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, oracle, csv, typeorm

I have a concern working with Oracle, TypeOrm, and NodeJs.
How can I input 1 million records found within a csv file?

The point is that I have to load the content of an xlsx file to a table in oracle, this file has around 1 million data or more.
The way I was doing this task was, converting from xlsx to json and from json, and that array save to database, but it was taking too long.
So now I transform to CSV, but how can I insert all the records from the CSV file into the oracle table?

I am using TypeOrm for the connection between Oracle and NodeJs

Comment: If your code has to iterate through each row of data and generate separate insert statements (as most ORMs do) then this is always going to be slow - the context switches between the code and the network, the network and the database, will slow processing by multiple orders of magnitude. Is there a reason you can't use a tool like SQL*Loader that is purpose-built to do bulk loads? You would even be better off storing the file as a JSON document in a single CLOB field in the database and using a database view and stored procedure to parse the JSON into the destination table.

Comment: The most performant way to load bulk rows via Node into Oracle would be by the node oracle driver https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/ which support array based loading